# importing multiple css issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm loading my css from on an aspx page.  On my local it looks fine, however; after looking at it after deployment none of css files in the Loader file seems to look to be loading.  All the files are in the same directory Folder1/Folder2/Css

css file (Loader.css)

```
@import url("C.ascx.css");
@import url("P.ascx.css");
@import url("E.ascx.css");
@import url("P1.ascx.css");
@import url("T.ascx.css");
@import url("D.ascx.css");
```

aspx

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:Literal id="DebugStyles" runat="server">
        <link href="Js/jQuery/jQueryUI/1.10.4/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Js/jQuery/jqGrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="Folder1/Folder2/Css/Loader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: Is there an error when you hit F12? What does it say? Are you sure they're in the deployed server?

Comment: The file is there. I'm working if it could be a directory issue from my local to the server. There are no errors that I see.